# Create and Instantiate objects in python when the program in running

Tags: python, instantiation

I'm making a program for calculate the electrical consumption of a building starting from the characteristics of the building, like the number of apartments and its type, I mean all not need to be of the same size for example, so I create a class called apartment, something like this:

```
class apartamento:


    def __init__(self):
        self.area = 0
        self.cantidad = 0
        self.altura = 0
        self.personas = 0 
        self.area = 0
        self.dotacion = 0
        self.cto_alum = 0
        self.cto_tug = 0
        self.cto_e = 0
```

So I could have let's say  thirty  apartments fifteen of 100m^2 and  others fifteen of 80m^2, the I want:

```
 type1 = apartamento()
 type2 = apartamento()


type1.area = 100
type2.area = 80
```

But since I dont know  how many types  of apartments are,  I need to create them when the program is running in a loop for example

When I say I don't know how many types of apartments are, I refer to the fact that this could be used for someone else, in differents sets of buildings, so in one It could be only one type of apartment and in other could be ten, and this has to be transparent to the user, now I have a spin box to put how many types of apartments are and then I create a table to put all the data of them, their size, number of person, number of circuits that it has, the problem is that them I have to make some calculations on this data so I want to instantiated every type of apartment as a object with the atributes that are put in the table, now I dont known how many types there will be, it depends of the building.

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what you want us to answer. Do you understand the concept of a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) in python and how to operate on/over them?

Comment: storing them in a dict using names for the keys would be a good approach, the only problem is  differentiating each different type

Comment: I think in do that, and use as many as I need, but them I would have to put a big number of elements in the list to be sure that never get out of bounds

Comment: I like the idea of use dictionaries but I had some problems with them, specifically with the criteria that takes python to order them, I put them in a specific order and them take the keys in a list to display and I get them in a apparently random way And  some keys name was missed.  

      for key in dic....
             list[i] = key

Answer (score 0):

Most complex programs solve this problem using a reload feature that they incorporate into some kind of daemon. For instance nginx

```
service nginx reload
```

Will update sites with new configuration parameters without having to actually restart the server.

In your case since this sounds like a more simple program you can always just have a python config file and read from it at a set interval.

```
import imp
config_module = imp.load_source("config", "/path/to/config.py")
```

And your configuration could look like

```
CONFIG = {
    "type1": {
        "altura": 10,
        "personas": 2,
        "cantidad": 5,
    },
    "type2": {
        ...
    }
}
```

At a certain interval you can just ask your program to look up the source of the configuration module and then you won't have to worry about your configuration being up to date.

Either that or you can just stop your program and then run it again in order to pick up the latest changes without having to wait for your config to reload.

After the configuration is updated you can create new apartment objects as you desire

```
apartmentos = {}
for type, values in config_module.CONFIG.iteritems():
     apartmentos[type] = Aparatmento(values)
```

Where `Apartmento` now accepts a new dictionary of configuration

```
class Apartmento(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        personas = config["personas"]
        altura = config["altura"]
        ...
```

Comment: I like the idea of use dictionaries but I had some problems with them, specifically with the criteria that takes python to order them, I put them in a specific order and them take the keys in a list to display and I get them in a apparently random way And some keys name was missed. for key in dic.... list[i] = key –

Comment: I mean does it matter the way the keys are ordered when you print the dictionary? The dictionary is just used to serve as a storage device for your different types of apartments. If there is a key missing then you should probably check your code to ensure that each apartment type is being iterated over correctly. Also if you have keys of duplicate name their data *will* get overwritten

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what exactly is it that you need, this is my take on it. 
It's most likely the dumbest approach to it. It looks to me like all you want to create is a building with some fixed number of apartments, some of which are of type 1 some of which are type 2.

Types of apartments don't sound to me like something that is preset, but more like something that is specific to each building and its plans. I.E. some buildings have apartments split in 2 categories, 100m^2 and 80m^2 and some have 90 and 50?

```
`class apartment:
    def __init__(self, area):
        self.area = area

class building:
    def __init__(self, ntypesOfapartments):
        self.ntypesOfapartments = ntypesOfapartments
        self.apartments = list()
        for i in range(ntypesOfapartments):
            area = input("Area of {0}. type of apartment: ".format(i))
            n = input("Number of apartments of area {0}: ".format(area))
            for j in range(int(n)):
                self.apartments.append(apartment(area))

    def __str__(self):
        desc = "Building has {0} types of apartments \n".format(self.ntypesOfapartments)
        desc += "Total number of rooms is {0}.".format(len(self.apartments))
        return desc
```

So you can instantiate a building with n different apartment types, and then define your apartment types interactively in the interpreter.

```
>>> test = building(2)
Area of 0. type of apartment: 100
Number of apartments of area 100: 5
Area of 1. type of apartment: 80
Number of apartments of area 80: 10
>>> print(test)
Building has 2 types of apartments 
Total number of rooms is 15.
>>>
```

Of course it would be a lot better to use a more sensical data structure than a list to hold the apartments, like a dictionary. That way you could access apartment type 1 in a dictionary under which you could have a list of all apartments that match your defined type 1.

This also very depends on the type of calculations you want to do with them? What are all the important data that you have to use in those calculations? In this example I only instantiate apartment area, if it turns out that number of people that live in it, is important to your calculations too, then it doesn't make sense to instantiate all of that by hand. Also what do you mean you don't know how many apartment types there are? What do you consider as a "running python program"? Do you mean interpreter, or are you writing something else?